# PHP New line character Windows vs. Macintosh

Tags: php, macos, newline

For a user input I do this:
`$var=str_replace(array('\r','\n'),'',$var);`

Works well on Windows, removing any new lines.
However, on the Mac (+Firefox) it somehow replaces the new lines with a `\` character.

Any clues as to why that happens?

Comment: did u get this to work ?

Answer (score 8):

I'm surprised it works on Windows.

Usually, for PHP to interpret control characters, they need to be in double-quoted strings, eg

```
array("\r", "\n")
```

Comment: It's converted to string, that's why it works with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

set the value `auto_detect_line_endings` to on in `php.ini` file
or `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);`