# CSV new Line Character

Tags: php, excel, parsing, csv, export-to-csv

I have an Excel Template that i use to fill in data and export that to CSV to populate the following page on my website.

http://play.mink7.com/ifocus_v4/careers.php

When i export the file in Windows i get the formatting for the new line charcter right. But when i export the same excel file from MAC i dont get the new line character.

```
Windows File
play.mink7.com/ifocus/win.csv
```

and

```
MAc File
play.mink7.com/ifocus/mac.csv
```

.

My Code

```
<?php 

include_once("libs/csv2json/CSVParser.php");

$jsonParser = CSVParserFactory::Create("json");
$path = "uploads/jobs.csv";

//This property will use the first row to convert the results into a
//json object array
$jsonParser->IsFirstRowHeader = true;
$jobs = $jsonParser->Parse($path);

$jobs = json_decode($jobs, true);

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>iFocus - Careers</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.34639.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.accordion.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="header" class="wrapper">
  <header class="container">
    <div id="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png" width="185" height="69" alt="ifocus logo"></a></div>
    <nav id="primaryNav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about_us.php">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="case_studies.php">Case Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonials.php">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="careers.php">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </header>
</div>
<div id="mainBody">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Careers</h3>
    <h4>iFocus is looking for experienced professionals in the following areas: </h4>
    <p>Email your resume to jobs@ifocussystec.com</p>
    <div class="active-jobs">

    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach($jobs as $j): ?>
      <h3 class="accordion" id="nav-section<?php echo $i++; ?>"><?php echo $j['job_code']." - ".$j['title']; ?><span></span> </h3>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <p><strong>Relevant Experience:</strong> <?php echo $j['experience']; ?></p>

        <p><strong>Job Description::</strong></p>
        <?php $job_desc = explode("\n", $j['job_desc']);?>
        <ul>
          <?php foreach($job_desc as $jd):?>
          <li><?php echo $jd; ?></li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

        <p><strong>Skill Set:</strong></p>
        <?php $skillsets = explode("\n", $j['skillsets']);?>
        <ul>
          <?php foreach($skillsets as $s):?>
          <li><?php echo $s; ?></li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

        <p><strong>Key Words:</strong> <?php echo $j['keywords']; ?></p>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>


    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('.accordion').accordion({
                        defaultOpen: 'nav-section1',
                        cookieName: 'accordion_nav'
                });
        });

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lib Link: https://github.com/crosbymichael/php-csv-to-xml-json

i have tried using `"\r\n"` but it doesnt give the formating either

Comment: did you try `PHP_EOL`???

Comment: I'm not sure I see anywhere in this code where you're generating an Excel file

Comment: @elavarasanlee can u please point me out how to use that

Comment: @MarkBaker my template is in excel. i fill the data export to csv and import the csv on the server to display the content.

Comment: Then show the code where you're doing this.... all you've shown is a little bit of html display

Comment: @MarkBaker have added the code

Comment: `explode(PHP_EOL, $string);`

Comment: @elavarasanlee no use. just checked. see http://play.mink7.com/ifocus_v4/careers.php it still shows all in one row. as "Skills1 Skills2 Skills3"

Comment: @HarshaMV : I am using windows. No one is using MAC here in locality... :-/

Comment: But `PHP_EOL` is designed for this purpose only.

Comment: @elavarasanlee same here. the client uses a mac and we are stuck n not able to generate the csv but just work from the csv tehy are exporting

Comment: A similar problem / thread is posted here [similar thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830627/php-new-line-character-windows-vs-macintosh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHPs file functions do not reliably recognize line endings from Macs (if they use `\r` character, as Mac Excel does, if I recall correctly.)

You need to set [`auto_detect_line_endings`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings) in php.ini to true, then it will properly recognize line endings, whether they are `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`.

This setting is PHP_INI_ALL, which means that it can be set anywhere, i.e., in php.ini, in `.htaccess` for a particular directory, or even with `ini_set`, e.g., `ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true)`