# Starting a newline for CSV in foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I need to start a new line every time it loops through and adds to the CSV document that is getting generated.

Code:

```
if(is_array($results_top_pages->getRows())){
        $name = rand();
        $myfile = fopen("bin/".$name.".csv", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        foreach($results_top_pages->getRows() as $top_page){
             $txt = array($top_page[0]. ",".$top_page[1]);
             fputcsv($myfile, $txt);
        }
        fclose($myfile);
    }
```

I have tried the following:

```
 - array($top_page[0]. ",".$top_page[1]. "\n");
 - array($top_page[0]. ",".$top_page[1]. "\r\n");
 - array($top_page[0]. ",".$top_page[1]. "<br>");
```

As well as all the above with `''` instead of `""`

Still no luck. Everything that is generated is all one line when opened in excel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520282/csv-new-line-character Perhaps this?

Comment: put comma first and then put \r\n

Answer (score 0):

It should detect the line endings. From [putcsv doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php):

> Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the quoted comma in `$txt = array($top_page[0]. ",".$top_page[1]);` Do this instead:

```
$txt = array($top_page[0], $top_page[1]);
```

`fputcsv` automatically puts line endings. What you're actually doing in your example is sending a single element array.