# PHP .csv Parsing Windows / Mac

Tags: php, arrays, windows, macos, csv

I'm a beginner in this field so please excuse any mistakes I make in terms or language, I'm having issues with a program that I inherited (and don't fully understand) and am looking for a bit of help.

It's built in PHP and was working on a Mac but is not working on a Windows machine - they're both running the same version of PHP (7.1.0.) The program is reading a csv line by line but on windows the loop stops after the first iteration / line - after the *actual* first line (which are column headers) is skipped.

This sets up the array and is working fine on both machines:

```
$firstRow = null;
$i = 0;


$file = null;
$currentfig = null;

foreach ($relarray as $row) {
    if($i == 0) {
        echo "first line";
        $firstRow = $row;
    }
    else {
        // check which file is available
        if($currentfig != $row[0]) {
            $currentfig = $row[0];
            if($file != null)
                fclose($file);
            $file = fopen("csv/".$currentfig.".csv", "w");
            mkdir ("folders/" . $currentfig);
        }

        $csvLine = fputcsv($file, $row);


        echo "others";
        echo "<dl>";
        for($o = 0; $o < count($row); $o++) {
            echo "<dt>$firstRow[$o]</dt><dd>$row[$o]</dd>";
        }
        echo "</dl>";
    }
    $i++; 
}
```

Then this creates the line by line process on the array:

```
if($csvFile == null) {
  $csvFile = 'TempSheet.csv';
}
    echo "<h1>Processing $csvFile </h1>";
    $csvData = file_get_contents($csvFile);
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
    $relarray = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
      if (!$line){
        $line = null;
}
      else {
    $relarray[] = str_getcsv($line);
    echo "rel array is";
    print_r($relarray);
}
}
```

At this point, on the mac it creates and prints a series of arrays, one for each row, all contained in one larger array. On windows it creates just one array with 
all of the elements from all rows within it.

I then take individual elements from this above one using a variety of these:

```
foreach ($relarray as $row) {
    $subtitles = $row[18];
        echo $subtitles . "<br />";
        $subtitles = str_replace("&", "&amp;", str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $subtitles));
        $starray[]=$subtitles;    
    }
```

Here ^ on a Mac printing the '$starray' displays the full 5 values whereas on Windows it only displays the initial one.

I've tried a few things to no avail; including using variations of line break signifiers and changing the php.ini settings as suggested here: [CSV new Line Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520282/csv-new-line-character)

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions or help, please let me know if you need further information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
```

Your problem is that the CSV file is parsed using `PHP_EOL` as line-ending character, but this constant has different values depending on the environement running the code (`\r\n` on Windows and `\r` or `\n` on Mac depending on pre/post OSX).

If your file has been created/saved on a Mac, it must've been saved with a `\n` at the end of each line (assuming the Mac is running a post-OSX version), and Windows search for a `\r\n` as the line end.

The consequence of this is that Windows cannot find its own line-ending characater and thinks it only has 1 big line containing all the data.

In addition to that, changing `auto_detect_line_endings` doesn't work in you case because you use `file_get_contents` which does not read line by line but the whole file at once and doesn't care about the line-ending.

So, what you could try is to enable `auto_detect_line_endings` and replace your following piece of code:

```
$csvData = file_get_contents($csvFile);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$relarray = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  if (!$line){
    $line = null;
  }
  else {
    $relarray[] = str_getcsv($line);
    echo "rel array is";
    print_r($relarray);
  }
}
```

By something like:

```
$csvFileHandle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
$relarray = array();

if($csvFileHandle) {
  while($csvLine = fgetcsv($csvFileHandle)) {
    $relarray[] = $csvLine;
  }
  fclose($csvFileHandle );    
}
```

Which will actually make use of the `auto_detect_line_endings` configuration and will correctly detect you CSV file endings + split each line in fields (`$csvLine`) and add them to `$relarray`.